# System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#

I am new to .Net. I am trying to calculate age. However getting below error.

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Below is code snippet.

```
static void Main()
    {
        var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dateOfBirth = new DateTime(1995, 04, 17);
        var date = dateAndTime.Date;
        int age = Convert.ToInt32(date - dateOfBirth);
        Console.WriteLine("Your age is " + age);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dateOfBirth = new DateTime (1995, 04, 17);
        double age = (dateAndTime - dateOfBirth).Days / 365;           
        Console.WriteLine("Your age is " + Math.Round(age));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. The result of that subtraction operation is a `TimeSpan` object which has properties you can use for that.

I have changed the code to resume the following using a TimeSpan and I'll give some notes.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
    var dateOfBirth = new DateTime(1995, 04, 17);
    var date = dateAndTime.Date;
    var ageTimeSpan = date - dateOfBirth;
    var age = ageTimeSpan.TotalDays / 365; // TotalDays is a double.
    Console.WriteLine($"Your age is {age}");
}
```

Total Days is a `double` for all the days that have elapsed in that time. You divide by the number of days in a year to get the years. Because it is a double you get the decimal points as well. If you wanted it as an integer, you can cast that to int using `var age = (int)ageTimeSpan.TotalDays / 365;` and the result will just be an int.